# Mapping 2 lists in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 python list like follows,

```
list1=[['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['h',5]]
list2=[['d',1],['e',2],['f',3],['g',4]]
```

Now elements of list within `list1` are sometimes common to elements of list within `list2`.

I want to get a third list (only for common elements) as follows,

```
list3=[['a',1,'d'],['b',2,'e'],['c',3,'f']]
```

And I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: And what should happen if there are *multiple* matches for a number? Or 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your second list in a dictionary; looking up connections is then trivial in a list comprehension:

```
mapping = {}
for a, b in list2:
    mapping.setdefault(b, []).append(a)
list3 = [[a, b] + mapping[b] for a, b in list1 if b in mapping]
```

This is a O(N + M) solution, e.g. it'll grow linearly the more elements you put into `list1` and `list2`.

It'll also handle more than one match; e.g. if any of the integers in the second position appear more than once in `list2`.

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3], ['h', 5]]
>>> list2 = [['d', 1], ['e', 2], ['f', 3], ['g', 4]]
>>> mapping = {}
>>> for a, b in list2:
...     mapping.setdefault(b, []).append(a)
... 
>>> [[a, b] + mapping[b] for a, b in list1 if b in mapping]
[['a', 1, 'd'], ['b', 2, 'e'], ['c', 3, 'f']]
```

If just one element should be appended, use `mapping[b][:1]`. If you need to include elements from `list1` that do *not* appear in `list2`, use `mapping.get(b, [])` and drop the `if b in mapping` filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check only corresponding elements if they have the same number the following suffices:

```
list3 = [(a, b, c) for (a, b), (c, d) in zip(list1, list2) if b == d]
```

Comment: This one is perfect too. Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
list3 = []
for e1 in list1:
    for e2 in list2:
        if e1[1] in e2:
            list3.append([e1[0], e1[1], e2[0]])
```

I should note that this solution will check for generally if the second entry of `e1` is anywhere in `e2`.  If you only want to compare the second entries of each you can use:

```
if e1[1] == e2[1]:
```

instead

Comment: Thank you @sedavidw, I am not sure who marked you down, but your answer is perfect too. And I am marking it up again. But yes, Martijn Pieters's answer will work faster for huge lists. Thank you